Fill with a white PlaneGeometry the viewport with exact size
I am trying to paint white the viewport in threejs with a planeGeometry. The reason is that I need the view plane with size and transform (rotation and position).
These are my two fails tries:
    function createFullScreenPlane() {
        const aspect = camera.aspect;
        const frustumHeight = 2 * Math.tan(THREE.MathUtils.degToRad(camera.fov) / 2) * camera.position.z;
        const frustumWidth = frustumHeight * aspect;

        const planeGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(frustumWidth, frustumHeight);
        const planeMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xffffff });
        const planeMesh = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeometry, planeMaterial);

        planeMesh.lookAt(camera.position);

        scene.add(planeMesh);
    }

And:
    function createFullScreenPlane() {

        const topLeft = new THREE.Vector3(-1, 1, -1);
        const bottomRight = new THREE.Vector3(1, -1, -1);

        topLeft.unproject(camera);
        bottomRight.unproject(camera);

        const width = bottomRight.x - topLeft.x;
        const height = topLeft.y - bottomRight.y;

        const planeGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(width, height);
        const planeMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xffffff, side: THREE.DoubleSide });
        const plane = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeometry, planeMaterial);

        plane.position.copy(camera.position).add(camera.getWorldDirection(new THREE.Vector3()).multiplyScalar(1));

        const posCamera = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        posCamera.unproject(camera);
        console.log(topLeft, bottomRight, posCamera, camera.position);

        plane.lookAt(camera.position);

        scene.add(plane);
    }


If I understood you correctly, you need to cover the viewport with a responsive plane... You can rendering it in several ways, depending on your needs and what the plane is supposed to do. If it is to be a simple mesh covering only the viewport, it seems to me that there is no need to use a PerspectiveCamera, it is easier to simplify your life and use a OrthographicCamera that is more adequate to these [2D] circumstances.


*{margin:0};
<script type="importmap">
  {
"imports": {
  "three": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.170.0/build/three.module.js",
  "three/addons/": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.170.0/examples/jsm/"
}
  }
</script>

<script type="module">
import * as THREE from "three";

const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(-1, 1, 1, -1, 0.1, 10);
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

const g = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(2, 2);
const m = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xf11fff });
const p = new THREE.Mesh(g, m);
scene.add(p);

camera.position.z = 1;

function responsive() {
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    camera.left = -1;
    camera.right = 1;
    camera.top = 1;
    camera.bottom = -1;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
}

window.addEventListener('resize', responsive, false);

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
animate();


</script>



But when you need a perspective camera, try this solution which is an extension of the first snippet. Try to calculate frustum based on camera.near(which creates situation, when the distance of the camera to the nearest object to remain constant, in your case plane) and not based on the camera positioned on the z-axis, how you tried rendering.


*{margin:0};
<script type="importmap">
  {
    "imports": {
      "three": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.170.0/build/three.module.js",
      "three/addons/": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.170.0/examples/jsm/"
    }
  }
</script>

<script type="module">
import * as THREE from "three";

const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 100);
camera.position.z = 5;

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

function createFullScreenPlane() {
    const aspect = camera.aspect;
    const frustumHeight = 2 * Math.tan(THREE.MathUtils.degToRad(camera.fov) / 2) * camera.near;
    const frustumWidth = frustumHeight * aspect;

    const planeMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xf11fff, side: THREE.DoubleSide });
    const planeMesh = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneGeometry(frustumWidth, frustumHeight), planeMaterial);
    planeMesh.renderOrder = -1;
    planeMesh.material.depthTest = false;
    
    planeMesh.position.copy(camera.position).add(camera.getWorldDirection(new THREE.Vector3()).multiplyScalar(camera.near));
    planeMesh.lookAt(camera.position.clone().add(camera.getWorldDirection(new THREE.Vector3())));

    scene.add(planeMesh);
}

createFullScreenPlane();

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

animate();

window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    scene.clear();
    createFullScreenPlane();
});
</script>



Bonus trick.
I recently had a project where I had to use the functionality you describe, with the difference that I had to use a ShaderMaterial. When you have such a situation, you don't have to use projectionMatrix and modelViewMatrix to transform the vertex positions, just shorten gl_Position
from:
gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);

to:
gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0);

But that's just a side note...

I found the solution.
The code then defines the corners of a plane in view space and unprojects them to world space using the camera.  To correctly center the plane, the geometric center of the plane is calculated and subtracted from each vertex. This centers the geometry at the origin.  A BufferGeometry is created from these adjusted points, and a Mesh is created and positioned at the calculated center. The mesh is then added to the scene. I added a testing to check the center: a red sphere is created and added as a child to the plane mesh, positioned at the origin of the plane's local coordinates.
import {OrbitControls} from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';
import {
    BoxGeometry,
    BufferGeometry,
    DoubleSide,
    GridHelper,
    Mesh,
    MeshBasicMaterial,
    PerspectiveCamera,
    Scene,
    SphereGeometry,
    Vector3,
    WebGLRenderer
} from "three";

const scene = new Scene();


const camera = new PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
scene.add(camera);


camera.position.set(7, 3, 15);
camera.lookAt(scene.position);

camera.updateMatrixWorld(true);


const renderer = new WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);


const size = 50;
const divisions = 10;
const gridHelper = new GridHelper(size, divisions);
scene.add(gridHelper);


const cube = new Mesh(
    new BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1),
    new MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x00ff00})
);
scene.add(cube);


const topLeft = new Vector3(-1, 1, 0);
const topRight = new Vector3(1, 1, 0);
const bottomRight = new Vector3(1, -1, 0);
const bottomLeft = new Vector3(-1, -1, 0);


topLeft.unproject(camera);
topRight.unproject(camera);
bottomRight.unproject(camera);
bottomLeft.unproject(camera);
console.log("vertex", topLeft, topRight, bottomRight, bottomLeft);


const geometry = new BufferGeometry()
const points = [topLeft, topRight, bottomRight, bottomLeft];


const center = new Vector3();
points.forEach(point => center.add(point));
center.divideScalar(points.length);


const adjustedPoints = points.map(point => point.clone().sub(center));
geometry.setFromPoints(adjustedPoints);
const indices = [
    0, 1, 2,
    0, 2, 3
];
geometry.setIndex(indices);
geometry.computeVertexNormals()

const material = new MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xffffff, side: DoubleSide});
const mesh = new Mesh(geometry, material);
mesh.position.copy(center);
scene.add(mesh)


mesh.updateMatrixWorld(true);
const worldPosition = new Vector3();
mesh.getWorldPosition(worldPosition);
console.log("World Position of mesh:", worldPosition);


const sphereGeometry = new SphereGeometry(0.1, 32, 32);
const sphereMaterial = new MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xff0000});
const sphere = new Mesh(sphereGeometry, sphereMaterial);
mesh.add(sphere);
sphere.position.set(0, 0, 0);


const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
controls.listenToKeyEvents(window);

const animate = () => {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    controls.update();
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
};
animate();

